# How to create index for a table in SQL so that it can return the results that satisfy requirements from multiple tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

This is an example from a real world SQL application problem. 
I am a new user of SQL.

Design a (SQL) `SELECT` statement that returns a list of names for all non-test accounts that live in Michigan and include what it returns.

```
Table: CustomerAcct_tab 

  id    first_name  last_name   address_id  account_type_code
 234    John        Smith       123         A
 342    Mary        Ryan        223         C
 210    Mark        Jackson     398         B
 678    Bill        Monroe      232         C
 789    JoAnne      Hill        300         D

 Table: Address_tab 

  id    State   
 123    MI  
 223    TX  
 398    CA  
 232    MI  
 300    CA  

 Table: AccountType_tab 

 code   is_test_account 
   A    TRUE    
   B    FALSE   
   C    FALSE   
   D    TRUE
```

My solution:

```
SELECT first_name, Last_name
FROM CustomerAcct_tab
INNER JOIN Address_tab ON CustomerAcct_tab.address_id = Address_tab.id 
INNER JOIN AccountType_tab ON CustomerAcct_tab.account_type_code = AccountType_tab.code 
WHERE is_test_account = FALSE AND Address_tab.State = MI
```

But, I think it may not be correct.

My coworker suggested that I need to create some indexes for the CustomerAcct_tab otherwise it is wrong and but I do not know how and why .

Comment: Your code looks correct to me. Why do you want to create indexes?

Comment: Indexes should never affect the correctness of an answer; they may affect the speed with which the answer is obtained, and you create them in the hope that they will speed up the queries.  Beware creating so many indexes that table updates take much longer and that cost outweighs the performance benefit from using them.

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking how and where to create an index to suit this query, I would suggest:

```
create index Address_tab_State_index on Address_tab(State);
create index CustomerAcct_tab_address_id_index CustomerAcct_tab(address_id);
```

and re-factor the query to select the tables in the order most advantageous for these indexes:

```
SELECT first_name, Last_name
FROM Address_tab
JOIN CustomerAcct_tab ON CustomerAcct_tab.address_id = Address_tab.id
JOIN AccountType_tab 
    ON CustomerAcct_tab.account_type_code = AccountType_tab.code 
    AND is_test_account = FALSE
WHERE Address_tab.State = MI
```

This query filters out non-matching rows as early as possible during execution, thus joining in the minimum number of rows from subsequent tables.

Note the use of the condition `is_test_account = FALSE` in the `ON` clause, rather than in the `WHERE` clause, thus trimming a little execution overhead off (avoiding filtering in the joined result).

Also note that you probably *already* have an index defined for `CustomerAcct_tab(address_id)` since it is a foreign key column.

Comment: Good answer--I'd emphasize that his code will not produce a different answer based on the existence of these indexes instead of his coworker's insinuation that "I need to create some indexes for the CustomerAcct_tab otherwise it is wrong "

Comment: @Bohemian, thanks ! Can you explain what the possible benefits of creating index in SQL ? thanks !

Comment: @Bohemian,I think account_type_code should be created as an index because the query needs to search test_account in accounttype_tab. right ?

Comment: Don't bother putting an index on a boolean field: There are only two values, so an index would be useless, as (on average) both values will each match half the rows. Better to simply scan the table. As a general rule, database won't use an index unless there are at least 11 different values and there is a reasonable distribution of rows between them (as collated via `ANALYZE TABLE` command).

Answer (score -1):

If I understand your question correctly, the problem that your co-worker pointed out is that the account_type code should be a number rather than a character or a string. Though it is possible to index a string as a foreign key it is not common.
This is the correct query :

```
SELECT first_name, Last_name FROM CustomerAcct_tab

INNER JOIN Address_tab ON CustomerAcct_tab.address_id = Address_tab.id

INNER JOIN AccountType_tab ON CustomerAcct_tab.account_type_code = AccountType_tab.code

WHERE AccountType_tab.code <> 'A' AND Address_tab.State = MI
```

Comment: Where did you pull the "WHERE AccountType_tab.code <> 'A'" from? There is nothing like that implied in the question